# Nested loop efficiency in c

Tags: c, optimization, nested-loops

Which is better way and Why?

Case 1:

```
for(i=0; i< 100; i++)
 for(j=0; j< 10; j++)
  printf("Hello");
```

case 2:

```
for(i=0; i<10; i++)
 for(j=0; j< 100; j++)
  printf("Hello");
```

Comment: In this case there is no appreciable difference. Differences in performance arise when you access a 2D array for example, where memory layout matters.

Comment: Probably the first, because it makes less assignments to `j` (`=0`) in the inner loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out which nested for loop is better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986632/how-to-find-out-which-nested-for-loop-is-better)

Comment: @M.SChaudhari Not a good duplicate, because the accepted answer speaks of different scenario with cache problems, which doesn't apply here.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov It has to perform either 100x10 or 10x100 assignments. Same thing. The execution time for those assignments should be constant. There's no obvious reason why having less assignments in the inner loop would improve efficiency.

Comment: @Lundin: isn't it the other way around?
@RuslanOsmanov: You get 1000 executions of ´j++´ in any case.
For case 1 we have 100 executions of `i++` and ´j=0´ while you only get 10 executions in case 2.

Comment: @Gerhardh, I meant that the `j=0` operation is performed 100 times in the first case, and 10 times in the second case. Is it right? It's probably a single assembly instruction, and is not valuable in practice. I'm saying "probably" because we don't know for sure how a compiler will optimize the code.

Comment: @lund That just means the answer is wrong/irrelevant, not that the question is not a duplicate. The accepted answer is just as wrong/irrelevant to the original question!

Comment: @CodyGray When moderating SO, it is important to preserve the duplicate questions with the best answers. Just because someone asked the question before, doesn't mean that _this_ question should be closed as duplicate to the previous one. It may very well be the other way around: the old question should be closed as duplicate. There is no need to preserve an old question with bad answers just because it is older than newer duplicate questions with better answers.

Comment: With `printf` in the middle? Are you kidding?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, neither form is better or faster. The compiler might even optimize both versions into code which only uses one loop, in which case both versions will yield identical machine code.

**EDIT**

I compiled both versions with gcc -O3 and both versions gave identical (although cryptic) machine code (x86):

```
0x00402CF0  push   %rsi
0x00402CF1  push   %rbx
0x00402CF2  sub    $0x28,%rsp
0x00402CF6  mov    $0xa,%esi
0x00402CFB  callq  0x4022f0 <__main>
0x00402D00  mov    $0x64,%ebx
0x00402D05  lea    0x12f4(%rip),%rcx        # 0x404000
0x00402D0C  callq  0x402ba8 <printf>
0x00402D11  sub    $0x1,%ebx
0x00402D14  jne    0x402d05 <main+21>
0x00402D16  sub    $0x1,%esi
0x00402D19  jne    0x402d00 <main+16>
0x00402D1B  xor    %eax,%eax
0x00402D1D  add    $0x28,%rsp
0x00402D21  pop    %rbx
0x00402D22  pop    %rsi
0x00402D23  retq
```

Code used for benchmarking, `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -O3`:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

#define I 100  // only change these 2 constants between builds
#define J 10

int main (void)
{
  for(int i=0; i<I; i++)
    for(int j=0; j<J; j++)
      printf("Hello");

  return 0;
}
```

---

Efficiency problems only arise when you do things like this:

```
// BAD, enforces poor cache memory utilization
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    array[j][i] = something;

// BAD, enforces poor cache memory utilization
for(j=0; j<n; j++)
  for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    array[i][j] = something;

// GOOD, optimized for data cache
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
  for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    array[i][j] = something;
```

Comment: GCC's output is not identical for both functions. It is *almost* identical, but the nesting of the loops is reversed, just like in the C code. Different constants are moved into the loop counter registers. So looking at the disassembly just kicks the problem down one abstraction layer. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray It _is_ identical. I built the program twice with different constants then compared the disassembly with Winmerge (text comparison program).

Comment: Hmm. That is bizarre. All versions, all optimizer switches, all target architectures, everything I try generates the code I described. The only other thing I can think of is that you're using MinGW (since you mentioned WinMerge?), and that behaves differently than the official GNU builds. I don't have MinGW installed to test it.

Comment: @CodyGray Or that you are using functions. I'm indeed using MinGW64, a somewhat old version, 4.9.1.

Comment: It isn't related to functions. I tried your test code verbatim on the Godbolt compiler explorer, and I can't get it to *ever* generate the same code, regardless of options. I don't have GCC installed locally (only Clang and MSVC), so I can't test it anywhere else. (That said, GCC is well known for *not* applying as extensive of optimizations to the `main` function. It always assumes that `main` is on the cold path. I don't see it making a difference here, but it can, so it's not generally a good idea when analyzing the behavior of an optimizer.)

Comment: @CodyGray I think it is the functions. Now I tried your code with two functions, but in a program that actually calls them. Then they get inlined into a single loop in the caller. Identical code for both functions. Something you wouldn't see happening while just disassembling the stand-alone functions without a caller.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we're talking about the case where the code is compiled with optimization enabled, since it is meaningless to talk about "efficiency" or "performance" when optimizations are disabled…

These *should* compile to identical object code. All the loop bounds are compile-time constants, so the compiler could theoretically determine how many times the code in the body of the loop will be executed, fold everything into a single loop, and emit that code. If it wanted to (and it wouldn't, because this is very space-foolish and does not offer a significant improvement in speed), it could emit 10,000 sequential calls to the `printf` function. This is just basic loop unrolling, and almost any optimizing compiler does that nowadays.

In the real world, compilers don't perform magic (and they aren't generally tuned to optimize dumb code or recognize its patterns), so these snippets will actually compile to slightly different object code.

Looking at GCC's output, it applies the standard peephole optimizations to the loops, but it doesn't merge them. It also does the loops in exactly the way that you wrote them. [You can see](https://godbolt.org/g/5E9prB) that the code for `Test1` and `Test2` are basically identical, except for the fact that `Test1` goes around 100 times in the outer loop and 10 times in the inner loop, while `Test2` does exactly the opposite. This is just a matter of moving different constants into registers.

MSVC follows the same strategy when generating code. Its basic pattern optimizations for the loop structures are slightly different than GCC's, but the code is morally equivalent. The only difference between `Test1` and `Test2` is whether the outer loop spins from 0 to 100, or 0 to 10.

What about performance? Well, the only *right* way to answer this question would be to compile both samples and check. In fact, that's the only way you ever reach an objective answer to a performance question. But you'll immediately have a problem if you try to do that: the `printf` function in the loop will *massively dominate* the amount of time taken by anything else, causing your benchmark results to be noisy and meaningless. You'd need to figure out something else to do inside of the loop that would not have as significant of an effect on the time that you're trying to measure, and it would have to be something with side effects that prevent the compiler from trivially optimizing it out. This is why such microbenchmarks are exceedingly difficult to do correctly. They are also not particularly interesting; what you should be benchmarking is *real code*. This is not real code. So I won't even bother trying to get meaningful benchmark numbers out of it.

The only thing I'll allow myself to do is noodle a bit about the conceptual performance implications of the code generated for the two functions. I would *guess* that making the larger loop the inner loop (*i.e.*, `Test2`) would be *slightly* faster. Why? Well, because once the code gets loaded into the instruction cache, it is executed 100 times in rapid sequence, with the branch predictor successfully predicting the target of the branch in nearly all cases. This is as efficient as it gets for a tight loop. In the other case, you'd only get to do 10 iterations under these optimal conditions before bunking out and having to start over, which risks evicting code from the instruction cache. You'd have to test and/or really study the specifics of the code to see if that's actually a possibility, because it depends on the exact size of the code and how much cache your processor has available, but it's a theoretical concern.

Switching gears, [let's see what Clang generates](https://godbolt.org/g/WpltFD). Interesting! The code looks pretty different for the two test functions. With `Test1`, Clang has unrolled the inner loop completely and emitted 10 back-to-back calls to the `printf` function. This is then wrapped inside of a loop that spins 100 times. Again, it's consistent with the C code that you originally wrote, but since the inner loop had so few iterations, Clang's optimizer determined that it was probably a performance win to unroll it. And it's probably right. What happened with `Test2`? Well, sort of the same thing—it just unrolled it differently because you wrote the original code differently. It has unrolled the *outer* loop to give 10 back-to-back code sequences that loop from 0 to 100.

Continuing with our theme of breaking the cardinal rule of performance analysis, we'll skip benchmarking the output and just think about it conceptually. The first thing that jumps out is that `Test2` requires a *lot* more code—it takes more than twice as many bytes to encode those instructions (321 vs. 141 bytes). Smaller code isn't always faster, of course, but here, where there isn't otherwise a clear winner, I'd be inclined to err in the direction of smaller code. The only thing that might affect that analysis is if the amount of code inside the body of the unrolled loop in `Test1` was too much to fit in the cache. The loop bodies in `Test2` are *much* smaller, even though the *overall* code is larger, so they're virtually guaranteed to be hot in the cache. Having the code in the cache is *way* better for performance. Hmmm, I guess we won't be able to tell without benchmarking after all.

#### In summary:

- Answer performance questions by *benchmarking*.
- Always benchmark *real code*, not arbitrary test cases (because generating correct cases that give meaningful results is extremely difficult).
- Theoretically, a perfect optimizing compiler should translate these snippets into identical code.
  In practice, that may not be true. Different compilers emit slightly different code depending on how you write the code. However, all generate eminently sensible code, following the lead that you set in the original C source.
- Again, theoretically, these should have identical performance. In reality, it may be slightly more complicated than that. But in practice, it doesn't matter, because both will be *fast enough*. The difference we're talking is on the order of nanoseconds. You are wasting time worrying about this.

Comment: The real question is why gcc gave different results in your case but the same in mine. All I did was to put the loop inside main(), then build two times with different iterator ranges. Using `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra -O3`.